# I defined component and used it App.js but getting undefined error

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

When I try to access the relevant component under app.js, I get the error "WARNING in [eslint] rc\App.js Line 2:8: 'personAdd' is defined but never used no-unused-vars". When I run the project, I see tags in the form of  in html, but the component does not appear on the screen. I have included the codes below. Thanks in advance.
Note : Changes under .eslintrc.json didn't work.

App.js

```html
import React from 'react';
import personAdd from './screens/personAdd';

function App() {
    return (
      <personAdd /> 
    )
}

export default App;
```

personAdd.js

```html
import React from 'react';

class personAdd extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <div id = "personAdd">
                <h1>Kullanıcı Bilgileri</h1>
                <form>
                    <label htmlFor="id">Ad</label>
                    <input id="id"/>
                    <button>Add</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default personAdd;
```

index.js

```html
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
//import personAdd from './screens/personadd';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);

/*const personadd = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('personadd'));
personadd.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <personAdd />
  </React.StrictMode>
);*/
```

Comment: It’s not a JS error, but a linting error. It’s likely because the component has been named beginning with a lowercase letter

Comment: React components should be in PascalCase (`PersonAdd`, for example). Why are you using both function and class components? It would be better to stick with one or the other. I'm not clear what's going on in that last example. The code to attach `App` to the root should be enough.

Comment: I am very new to react field. The PascalCase(PersonAdd) case fixed the problem. I've been researching for a long time to detect the problem and I saw the method to add to index.js but it didn't work. That's why I commented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to manually create new root elements for every component you want to render.

React inserts an initial element 'root' into the DOM so that the app can render within that.

Try removing:

```js
/*const personadd = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('personadd'));
personadd.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <personAdd />
  </React.StrictMode>
);*/
```

If you want to render your personAdd component you can add it as a child of App as you've already done.

```js
function App() {
    return (
      <personAdd /> 
    )
}
```

The other reason you're getting these issues is because you're not using Pascal case when naming your components (PersonAdd).

```js
function App() {
    return (
      <PersonAdd /> 
    )
}
```

In addition as others have mentioned, stick to function components rather than class components.

I'd recommend having a look at the [React Beta Docs](https://beta.reactjs.org/) which now do everything with functional components. There are helpful walkthroughs on there that should help you out.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Yes, its work with PascalCase. Also the code worked without deleting the comment lines under index.js.

Comment: Yeah the comment lines aren't running I was just pointing out that you would never need to do this so you can delete them

Answer (score 1):

As @evolutionxbox said. Try naming the component with UpperCamelCase. It's used to specify a React element
https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#specifying-the-react-element-type

Also, it is now common to create components as functions and not Classes. Of course it's up to you if you do prefer classes.
https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#rendering-a-component